# Accessing global variable?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following code to login to a web service and store the authentication token:

```
loginViewController.h
@interface loginViewController : UIViewController<XMLRPCConnectionDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *SSO;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PASS;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *LoginError;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *token;
@end


loginViewcontroller.m
#import "loginViewController.h"

@implementation loginViewController
@synthesize SSO;
@synthesize PASS;
@synthesize LoginError;
@synthesize token;

- (IBAction)coreLoginClicked:(id)sender {

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://somesite"];  
    XMLRPCRequest *request = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithURL: URL];
    XMLRPCConnectionManager *manager = [XMLRPCConnectionManager sharedManager];

    [request setMethod:@"systemLogin"  withParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: SSO.text, PASS.text, nil]];
    [manager spawnConnectionWithXMLRPCRequest: request delegate: self];

    NSLog(@"Request body: %@", [request body]);





}

- (void)request: (XMLRPCRequest *)request didReceiveResponse: (XMLRPCResponse *)response {

    if (![response faultCode]) {
        token = [response object];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];


    NSLog(@"Response object: %@", [response object]);
}
```

I have this code in my view controller that is displayed after successful login:

```
loginViewController* login = [[loginViewController alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Token: %@", login.token);
```

The value of login.token is nil. What am I doing wrong here? Is this the incorrect way of setting and accessing a global variable?

I was following the tutorial on Objective-C from lynda.com, and this way how they did it.. but maybe I missed something.

Thanks!

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have global variables.

Comment: Objective-C is a strict subset of ANSI C, and thus implements global variables.  But the question seems to have nothing to do with global variables.

Comment: @hotpaw2 It's a superset as it includes everything C includes plus the Objective-C primitives.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt As hotpaw suggests, Objective-C definitely has global variables in the same way that C has them.

Comment: @Jason : Thanks for pointing out my typo/swapped ordering.  Obj C is the superset.  C is the subset.

Comment: Correction: Objective-C *does* have global variables but in >99.9% of the cases you don't want to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You're allocating a new instance, which means it'll be empty. If you want to be able to store objects in a class, you will have to use *that* instance to get the variables back.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing token via self:

```
NSLog(@"Token: %@", self.token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second code bit does this:  creates a new instance of the loginVC, and then checks to see if it has a token.  You need to instantiate your loginVC, then do your login, and then it will have a value in token.  Whatever class/method instantiates the loginVC will then be able to check **that instance** of loginVC for the token.